# DQN: Clipping the reward to the interval of [-1,1]

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

My question is about implementing a DQN. I have seen some people use the actual rewards of the game and some clip it to [-1,1]. Is this just because they want to use their DQN for different Attari games and these games have different rewards or even if we only care about a specific game, it is good to divide all rewards to the maximum possible rewards to make them lie in [-1,-1]?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Clipping the rewards to lie in the [-1, 1] interval reduces the impact of extreme observations, making the model more robust.  Another common approach is to clip the gradient of the loss for a minibatch so that no single step is too extreme.  Whether or not these are helpful changes from case to case, but generally robust measures like these are helpful.